# Computing Riemann tensor components for Alcubierre metric

Tags: general-relativity, metric-tensor, curvature, warp-drives

I am currently trying to compute the Riemann tensor components for the [Alcubierre metric](https://arxiv.org/abs/gr-qc/0009013), and already, on the computation of the first component, I'm running into some issues.

The trouble component in question is $R^x_{\;txt}$ , so I've started with the formula:
$$
R^x_{\;txt} = \partial_x\Gamma^x_{\;tt} -\partial_t\Gamma^x_{\;xt}+\Gamma^x_{\;x\mu}\Gamma^\mu_{\;tt}-\Gamma^x_{\;t\mu}\Gamma^\mu_{\;xt}
$$
Using the Christoffel symbols provided by Mueller and Grave's [Catalogue of Spacetimes](https://arxiv.org/abs/0904.4184v3), I started computing the first term, $\partial_x\Gamma^x_{\;tt}$:
$$
\begin{align}
\partial_x\Gamma^x_{\;tt} &= \partial_x\frac{f^3f_xv_s^4-c^2ff_xv_s^2-c^2f_tv_s}{c^2} \\
&=\frac1{c^2}\Big(\partial_xf^3f_xv_s^4-\partial_xc^2ff_xv_s^2-\partial_xc^2f_tv_s\Big)
\end{align}
$$
And, again isolating the first term and computing further:
$$
\partial_xf^3f_xv_s^4 = f_xv_s^4\partial_xf^3 + f^3v_s^4\partial_xf_x + f^3f_x\partial_xv_s^4
$$
If my math is correct.

The area I'm having trouble is in the partial derivative $\partial_xv_s$. I can't quite understand how to compute it. For reference, $v_s$ is defined by Alcubierre as a function of time:
$$
v_s(t) = \frac{dx_s(t)}{dt}
$$
and $x_s(t)$ is simply described as an "arbitrary function of time", describing the trajectory of the hypothetical spacecraft in the scenario of the metric.

I don't quite see how the actual $x$ axis relates to this function, and so I'm at a loss as to how I should treat a derivative of the function with respect to $x$. What am I missing?

Comment: For simplicity, to start, you could just treat the case of a warpdrive spacecraft moving uniformly and take it to be a constant.

Comment: @G.Smith I do want my end result to work with changing speed, wouldn't that simplification prohibit that?

Comment: Yes, it would prohibit that, so hopefully someone will answer.

Comment: I’m tempted to say that it is simply a function of $t$ and not of the spatial coordinates, so $\partial_x v_s$ is zero but $ \partial_t v_s$ is nonzero. But I’m not sure if I’m thinking about it the right way, having never thought about this metric. But it seems similar to the Friedmann metric, where $a(t)$ is just a function of $t$.

Comment: @G.Smith Yeah, I'm pretty sure $v_s(t)$ is only a function of $t$. After your comment I took another look at the paper and it seems that $x_s$ is only applied to $x$ in $r_s$, not in $v_s$ or itself. Would that make $\partial_xv_s$ just 0?

Comment: Sorry, I don’t understand what “applying $x_s$ to $x$” is supposed to mean.

Comment: @G.Smith I mean that $x_s$ doesn't actually have anything to do with $x$ until it's used in the function $r_s(t)=\sqrt{(x-x_s(t))^2+y^2+z^2}$, where it is subtracted from $x$ in the calculation. So changing $x$ doesn't seem to change $x_s$, nor does it seem to change $v_s$.

Comment: OK. I’m convinced that $\partial_ x v_s=0$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As [G. Smith](https://physics.stackexchange.com/users/199630/g-smith) helped answer, $v_s(t)$ is a function that depends solely on time, and as such does not change across the x direction, so $\partial_xv_s(t) = 0$.
The function is defined as the derivative of a function named $x_s(t)$, which also depends only on time, and it's the name of this function which mislead me.